# White left margin in tikzposter

Tags: margins, tikzposter

I have troubles compiling plain `tikzposter` documents. Compiling something like

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{Block}{Content}


\end{document}
```

will lead to a white margin on the left side.
[image: resulting pdf]

Logfile: https://paste.ee/p/ZHN9E

Comment: I don't get that output (TeX Live 2018), can you add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`, run `pdflatex` again, and the add the `.log` file to your question?

Comment: There is also something wrong with the `\block`, the title should cover the whole width of it.

Comment: I'm also using TeX Live 2018. I added a link to a logfile.

Comment: (Better to add the lov directly to the question.) You're not using the `tikzposter.cls` that is in TL18 though, but one found in the same folder as your .tex file. Try renaming/moving/deleting that local version.

Comment: oops. Didn't realize I had a local version over there. Thanks!